# How to know if the kernel is compatible with v4l2loopback?

Tags: kernel-modules, compatibility, v4l2loopback

I want to use v4l2loopback to stream from OBS-Studio in Microsoft Teams or discord, but I'm not sure if it will work with my system (I also don't really understand the section "DEPENDENCIES" on the github page https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/ but I don't want my computer to "spit in my eye or do worse").

I run Ubuntu 20.04.1 and the kernel version is 5.8.0-55-generic.

How can I know if the v4l2loopback modules are compatibles with my kernel ?

Comment: You want / need to build it yourself? Ubontu comes with pre-built packages. In my case I *had to* build it myself running fake-cam (https://github.com/fangfufu/Linux-Fake-Background-Webcam#ubuntu-1804) - but for v20 it might work out of the box. Anyhow: using the bundled you should be insanely unlucky if it breaks anything. After all you *load a module* in to kernel during runtime. If for some reason it botches anything remove it `modprobe -r <module>`  or reboot if you like. (But I *do get* that it can be confusing and somewhat technical. But if you use OBS etc. you'll manage :)